# How (or why) the copy constructor is called?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Car
{
    int size = 4;
    int* tires = nullptr;

    Car()
    {
        cout << "ctor" << endl;
        tires = new int[size];
    }

    Car(const Car& car)
    {
        cout << "copy ctor" << endl;
        tires = new int[size];
        memcpy(tires, car.tires, size*sizeof(int));
    }

    Car& operator= (Car& car)
    {
        cout << "copy assignment operator" << endl;
        tires = new int[size];
        memcpy(tires, car.tires, size*sizeof(int));
        return *this;
    }

     ~Car()
    {
        cout << "dtor" << endl;
        delete tires;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout  << "starting..." << endl;

    Car car1;
    car1.tires[0] = 2;

//    Car car2(car1); // #1
    Car car2 = car1; // #2 I was expecting the assingment operator to be called here

    cout << car1.tires[0] << " " << car2.tires[0] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I understand why the copy constructor is called at #1, but how does it end up being called at #2?

Comment: Assignment is when you assign to a variable after creating it: `Car car2; car2 = car1;`

Comment: When `size` is always `4`, you can change `int* tires = nullptr;` to `int tires[4];`, then you do not have to `new` all that memory and you do not have to change `delete tires;` to `delete[] tires;`, because you can remove the line at all.

Comment: FYI -- 1) Your `operator=` leaks memory.   You failed to `delete[]` the old memory.  2) You used the wrong form of `delete` in the destructor.  It should be `delete []`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement:

`Car car2 = car1;`

is NOT assignment, like you are thinking. Assignment can happen only on an *existing* object, not when an object is being created.

The statement above is actually [initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) instead, specifically [Copy Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

> Syntax
>
> `T object = other;`   (1)
>
> ...
>
> The effects of copy initialization are:
>
> - ...
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a class type and the cv-unqualified version of the type of `other` is `T` or a class derived from `T`, the [non-explicit constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. That constructor is then called to initialize the object.
> - ...

So, in your case, the compiler finds the copy constructor is a match and treats the statement *as-if* you had written `Car car2(car1);` instead.

That is why the copy constructor is called.

Comment: And making the copy constructor explicit, `explicit Car(const Car& car)`, seems to prevent that of happening.

Answer (score 1):

A C++ compiler will call the assignment operator only for an object that already exists, to overwrite the values of this object with the values of another instance.

```
car car1,car2;
car2=car1;
```

And it will call the copy constructor in the below cases:

1. if the object is initialized with another instance.

   ```
     car car1;
     car car2=car1; //This is equivalent to car2(car1);
   ```
2. if an object is passed to a function as a non-reference parameter.

   Here you can see the parameter of func, where the obj2 is being initialized and not assigned.

   ```
    void func(car obj2)//not a reference parameter(car& obj2)
    {
     //
    }

    car obj1;
    func(obj1);
   ```
3. An object is returned from a function - I don't have an idea about this yet.

Initialization is when a new object or variable is being created to hold a value, and assignment is when an existing object or variable is set to hold a new value.

For the above assignment operator example, both the `car1` and `car2` objects hold a value (probably garbage) at the time of creation, and then are set to a new value.